# How to work out two images's degree of similarity using php

Tags: php, image, binary, similarity, image-comparison

there are two jpg files binary data,how to work out their degree of similarity using php.
if it is possible to get color infomation from binary code.what's more ,the server cant surport gd,it's a delegate server.

Comment: Well, do you have something else, like ImageMagick? If not, you should probably write your own function to decode jpg et al. Also: what would you consider "similar"? Average color?

Comment: no imageMagick either,i want to do something like using picutre search annother picture.

Answer (score 2):

These previous questions seem to be related:

- [How can I measure the similarity between two images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977/how-can-i-measure-the-similarity-between-two-images)
- [Image fingerprint to compare similarity of many images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596262/image-fingerprint-to-compare-similarity-of-many-images)
- [What algorithm could be used to identify if images are the "same" or similar, regardless of size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005115/what-algorithm-could-be-used-to-identify-if-images-are-the-same-or-similar-reg)
- [Duplicate image detection algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219185/duplicate-image-detection-algorithms)
- [Similar image search software (like TinEye)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700819/similar-image-search-software-like-tineye)
- [Looking for image similarity library that doesn't care about image dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446003/looking-for-image-similarity-library-that-dont-care-about-image-dimensions)